# Pythonic Way to structure module API with circular import

Tags: python, python-3.x, circular-dependency

How should I resolve the following circular dependency?

I have a file A that exposes API methods and delegates all the backend logic to a separate file, A_impl.

In A.py, I also expose an Enum which clients need to pass in as an argument to some of the API methods:

```
# A.py
import A_impl

class MyEnum(Enum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    THREE = 3

def A(x: MyEnum):
    return A_impl._A(x)
```

A_impl actually needs MyEnum:

```
#A_impl.py
from A import MyEnum

def _A(x: MyEnum):
    pass
```

One way to resolve this is to just merge the two modules together but that defeats the purpose of splitting it up for cleaner code in the first place. A_impl consists of dozens of helper functions and putting the public and private methods into one module was getting messy.

Comment: Can you put the `MyEnum` class in a third file that both `A.py` and `A_impl.py` import from?

Answer (score 3):

You can import `A_impl` inside the definition of `A` instead:

```
# A.py

class MyEnum(Enum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    THREE = 3

def A(x: MyEnum):
    import A_impl
    return A_impl._A(x)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to have `MyEnum` available when the `_A` function is defined or else the type hint won't know what the `MyEnum` class is.

Comment: no, you can't, because the `MyEnum` in the function annotation is evaluated at function-definition time. You'd get a `NameError` when importing the module.

Comment: is there any other way to do this? If I have 10 API methods, then I'd need to import 10x which feels a little goofy

Comment: @vgbcell You can also define `MyEnum` in a separate module that does not import `A.py` to avoid circular import.

Comment: @blhsing I thought of that too. Anyways, what is the consequence of having the import inside the function? If A() is called multiple times, will it import the whole module every time during invocation of A()? Or is there some caching mechanism of imports in place? Same question for multiple functions importing A_impl

Comment: All imports are only done once and are cached in `sys.modules` so there's no downside to importing a module inside a function. You can see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html for details.